# Linear functional and trace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, dual-spaces

I really need some help with this question:

> Let $V = M_{n \times m}(\mathbb{K})$ be a vector space of matrices, where $\mathbb{K}$ is some field and $f \in V^*$ a linear functional. Prove that there is a matrix $P \in V$ with $f(A) = \mbox{trace}(P^T A)$ for all $A \in V$.

---

So I have a functional $f$ and have to construct a Matrix $P$. I think the basis of $V$,

$$B = \left\{ E_{ij} \mid 1 \leq i \leq n, 1 \leq j \leq m \right\}$$

will be useful but I couldn't figure out what to do next.

Comment: Have you studied inner product in $\;V\;$ and Riesz Theorem?

Comment: No, we haven't done them yet.

Comment: Notice that $A\mapsto Trace(P^TA)$ is linear, so you just need to define it on a basis

Comment: Soo, on my Dualbasis of $V$?

Comment: The proof is pretty easy with inner product, orthonormal basis and etc....without it it will take me probably quite a while. Perhaps someone else...